# Dingo Api response->created | location and content example

Tags: rest, api, laravel, laravel-5, dingo-api

I am creating API with Laravel 5.2 and Dingo API package. When a user is created, I want to return `201` response with the new `$user->id`.

My Code

```
return $this->response->created();
```

As per [Dingo documentatio](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Responses#responding-with-created-response), I can provide a `location` and `$content` as parameters in the `created()` function.

My question is, what location information I need to return here and I tried to set my new user as `$content`, but it's not working or I am not sure what to expect.

Can someone please explain this `created()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this does is set the `Location` header, [as seen in the source](https://github.com/dingo/api/blob/d3f238e508f9ddd2d74784ce4431224060d96371/src/Http/Response/Factory.php#L48):

```
/**
 * Respond with a created response and associate a location if provided.
 *
 * @param null|string $location
 *
 * @return \Dingo\Api\Http\Response
 */
public function created($location = null, $content = null)
{
    $response = new Response($content);
    $response->setStatusCode(201);
    if (! is_null($location)) {
        $response->header('Location', $location);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

So, in your example since you're creating a new user, you might send the users profile page as the location, something like:

```
return $this->response->created('/users/123');
```

As for the content, as you can see in the function this sets the content on the return. In your case, it would probably be a json string with the new user information, something like:

```
return $this->response->created('/users/123', $user); // laravel should automatically json_encode the user object
```

Comment: Cool.. thanks. This is I wanted to know. Do you know Is there anyway I can use transformer with this content I want to return?

Comment: Well you're returning the raw content there, so in theory you could, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: @ArifulHaque did you found out how to return transformer data with created response?